# Why does the Spotify Web API throw a 500 error when getting playlists from a specific user?

Tags: spotify

This endpoint on Spotify's Web Api throws a 500 error for the username "spotify":

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists
```

Is this intentional on Spotify's end? Does Spotify not wants developers to access its playlists.

Note - All other usernames work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 500 error should always be treated as being unintentional. If the server side wants to limit access a response code in the 400 range should be used instead, like 403 or possibly 401. It is likely that there are so many different public playlists for the Spotify account that one of them has triggered a bug. If for some reason the error code 500 is intentional, it is still a bug, but in the API, which should be fixed.

I work at Spotify, but don't have direct access to this system. I will let people know.

Comment: I noticed it's throwing a 503 error now! I guess someone attempted a fix. Any timeline on when this bug gets resolved?

Comment: Update: It's now throwing a status: 502, message: 'Bad gateway.'

Comment: Just as jooon says in the answer, the API should return a 502 as the error is intentional. I'd just like to add that the error occurs temporarily, and we urge you to try again later. I realise that this isn't a viable solution in the long run and that we're looking at ways to resolve this for good.

Comment: Thanks @michaelt. I've yet to receive a successful callback for the user Spotify and I've been attempting the last couple weeks but I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: @AdamSoffer, may I ask what your use case is? Do you wish to access the playlists that are shown in the Browse/Start section?

Comment: @michaelt insight. Response includes number of followers. Looking for visibility into most popular.

Comment: Receiving a 500 error again. @michaelt Any update on this bug?

Comment: @AdamSoffer 500 or 502? There are still issues around the Spotify user I'm afraid.

Comment: @michaelt 500 again :/